# How can I know, to which topic the arrived message belongs?

Tags: mqtt, paho, android-open-accessory

I am developing an App and I am using MQTT protocol supported by Paho library.

I am subscribing to 10 topics, and there will be a messgae(s) published for one at least one topic. now, when I get notified about the arrival of a new messae, how can  i know to which topic it belongs?

**Update**:

[image: pic1][image: pic2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that you get when the message arrives should have a destination field which will contain the topic.

Comment: i do not have the destination field, all the properties i can access are posted above in the image..pease have a look at it

Comment: The string arg0 is the topic in this case